# Closing Processing windows but not terminate the process

Tags: java, processing

I am currently using Java to write an image processing program with a command-line interface. I decide to use Processing-Java as its library to deal with those images. There is a class I wrote to view those loaded images called by the main class. However, when I close the window instance, the main process will also be terminated. How can I able to close the window instance without terminating the whole program?

```java
    public static void showVolumes(List<CT_Volume> volumes) {
        String[] appletArgs = { "ImageViewer" };
        ImageViewer instance = new ImageViewer(volumes);
        runSketch(appletArgs, instance);
    }
```

This static method is called by the main class, which is the driver program showing the CLI interface and interacting with the user. The `CT_Volume`is an object that is used to encapsulate information of a set of images that being used, it contains a list of `PImage` so that the image viewer can display the images. The user can call this static method when they want to view the images loaded to the memory. I want to keep the main process called this static method after the window instance is terminated.

Comment: Use [`yourJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-) to change the behavior.

Comment: @Socowi That works with Swing. Does it also work with the Processing library?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I overlooked the `processing` part. Maybe you could add some details to your question, e.g. the code you used to create the window so that it is clear what type of window you are using.

Comment: Of what package and class is the window in question?

Comment: @Carter Can you share how you process the images ? In theory it should be possible to use PImage to process images from `main()` without instantiating a PApplet (the windowing environment)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Yes, I wrote a separate class to load Images and return a list of PImage to the main class. My program can load without initiating a PApplet. I also wrote another class, a typical processing one with setup() and draw() to display those images, and it contains a static method for the main class to call. I don't want my whole program terminated when I close this little image browser.

Comment: Ok, I understand a bit more now. You do want a UI, but for want the window to close. What OS are you using ? If you add `void exit(){println("exiting");super.exit()}` do you see the "exiting" message print in console ? And does it exit ? Are you using threads in your code ? (perhaps there's a thread still hanging ?)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Yes, there is "Process finished with exit code 0" in IDEA's console. So I guess when closing the windows, it triggers the System.exit(). I just browsed through Processing's source code and found something,
        this.frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                PApplet.this.exit();
            }
        });
    }. I am trying to override this method to see if it works.

Comment: What operating system are you using ? Does "existing" get printed at all ? Does your code use threads at all ? The code I mentioned above is overriding PApplet's [`exit()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#exit--) method. At this stage it's a lot of guess work and hard to run/replicate your setup.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I tried to override the exit() with your code and nothing printed. My code didn't use thread. The OS that I am currently using is Windows.

Comment: I can seem to replicate the issue without your project, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing sketches in P2D and JAVA2D renderer modes calls the PApplet instance’s `exitActual()` method, which contains the line `System.exit(0)` – a static method – which terminates the currently running Java virtual machine.

Overriding `exitActual()` with nothing (i.e. preventing the call to `System.exit(0)`) prevents sketches from closing others, fixing the issue, but introduces another problem in the case of P2D sketches: the window is not disposed properly when the cross is clicked.

#### Solution:

Override `exitActual()` to prevent the JVM (and all sketches) closing when one sketch is closed.

```
@Override
public void exitActual() {
}
```

Introduce the following code (suitable in `setup()`) such that P2D sketches are disposed properly:

```
if (getGraphics().isGL()) {
        final com.jogamp.newt.Window w = (com.jogamp.newt.Window) getSurface().getNative();
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowClosingMode.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to how the Java process is handling the termination signals sent from the terminal. The terminal sends a SIGHUP signal to all processes associated with it when it is closed.

There are generally 2 options when trying to segment the terminal from the process. You can either segment the process from the terminal with the `disown` command, or you can try to have the process ignore the termination signal by starting it with the `nohup` command.

I believe that it is the SIGHUP signal being sent to the JVM process that is causing your issues. See SIGHUP on the gnu page: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

To disown a started process, I would recommend the tutorial from TechAdmin (Very simple) https://tecadmin.net/close-terminal-without-killing-running-processes-on-linux/

To summarize:

```
 kill -STOP <PID OF PROCESS>
 bg
 jobs -l         # To find the job ID of the process (Optional)
 disown -h %1    # Where 1 specifies the first running process
                 # (Or you can specify the JOB ID)
```

A second option may be to use the `nohup` command to start the command. `nohup` will ignore the SIGHUP signal when it is sent to the process.

```
nohup java -jar yourJar.jar &
```

where `nohup` ignores the SIGHUP signal when it is sent to the process, and `&` runs the process in the background to start.

**NOTE:** This answer is written from a Linux perspective, and focuses on how the process is started and managed by terminals. I haven't used the Java-Processing library, but I'm hopeful that this answer will provide some insight toward the solution.